# Can't figure it out: Redirection showing old url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I'm using cpanel and tried using htaccess and it's not working.. I need to redirect prismafoto.com.ar to brujaurbana.com.ar/prisma but when it does the url that is shown is brujaurbana.com.ar/prisma
How can I do this?? thanksss :(

Comment: It sounds to me like everything is working perfectly?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Maybe you mis-typed the question? Or do you want to do the redirection without the address changing?

Comment: Please post the current htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are wanting to do a masked URL redirect. Meaning, you want the domain to redirect but stay the same in the URL bar.

http://webstarthelp.com/forwards.html

The above site has a great Masked URL Redirect.

Simply create a index.html file on prismafoto.com.ar and paste the generated code.
Make sure to clear the .htaccess file so redirects do not conflict.